# How to make clickable entire row?

Tags: php, html, row

I have this link to update a field on a table row

```
echo "<td data-target='precio' style='padding:0px 0px 0px 15px'>" . $row->precio . "<a href='#' data-role='update' data-id=" . $row->producto . "></a></td>";}
```

How can I make the entire row clickable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the entire row to be clickable, your `<a></a>` tag needs to be surrounding the `<tr></tr>` tags, not just the text itself. (Alternatively, use a JavaScript onclick-function)

Answer (score 0):

move $row->precio inside anchor

```
echo "<td data-target='precio' style='padding:0px 0px 0px 15px'><a href='#' data-role='update' data-id='" . $row->producto . "'>" . $row->precio . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: This only makes clickable the text. I want all the row

Comment: You could then use display:block; on the anchors to make the full row clickable.